# How to get output of db.serverStatus().connections through pymongo in python?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

In mongodb shell "`db.serverStatus().connections`" gives output something like:

```
{ 
"current" : 43,
"available" : 51157,
"totalCreated" : NumberLong(3988)
}
```

So, my concern is how to get the same output through pymongo.??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issue the MongoDB **[`command`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.command)** "serverStatus" to get the output and save it to a variable:

```
connections_dict = db.command("serverStatus")["connections"]
```